# Dynamic Website on static html

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I am trying to create a script that will display the contents of a folder, onto a newsticker, and I was wondering if anyone had a script that could run this.  I was thinking probably php, but it has no been working for me.

Thanks for the help

The software I am using is dreamweaver cs4

Comment: Well what kinda of content would you have in the folder? A plain text file or something else?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not been working for me"? Is PHP configured? What error messages are you getting? What do you expect to happen versus what is actually happening?

Comment: > but it has no been working for me.

Can you show us what hasn't worked for you, so we can give better imput ?

Comment: @dassouki, I agree we need a lot more details to help you out.

Comment: The content would be a text file, located on a share drive folder, and there are no error messages just nothing outputting.

Sorry for the lack of details im im a complete beginner

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have written some PHP, but are trying to run it locally without a server - for PHP to work you need a server. XAMPP is a good bet to do this locally, or you'll need to upload your file to some hosting that supports PHP.

Comment: at first i thoguht he wanted to do a <marquee> <?php echo file_name[] ?> </marquee>

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking why you're having trouble with it is because you just copy and pasted the code in a .html file and opening it on your local environment.

With that said, in order for it to run locally, you have to install php and a http server. The code is done on server side, not client side. So either get a hosting service that supports php or download and install your own server and php.

Also, if you already have the above, the code has to be surrounded by a < ?php and ? > tags(without spaces). If you're running it on cli, then you need to make sure you give it execution permission with the path to php, OR execute php < name of script >.

Last, the code you presented provides major security flaws. The first of which is where will the "$dir_path" variable be set? Will that be user given, or will you specify the variable?

Whenever you allow users to view your file system, always make sure you give limitations to it. For example, let's say you did this:

www.example.com/newsticker.php?path=/www/files/newsticker

looks innocent enough, but a clever hacker could say let me try....

www.example.com/newsticker.php?path=/

And so fort.

So be careful and don't allow users to specify directories or execute code.